# Physical connection is not usable

Tags: sql, powerbuilder

```
SQLState=08S02
Microsoft native client 10.0
Physical Connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]
```

I have database on different server and application on different server.
it is security reason, so both database and application will not on same server.
Application is configured in window schedular which run every night round about 11 PM.
Hw to handle this in code or any other solution?

Comment: So is the issue you lose database connectivity when the application is running or the application cannot establish a connection in the first place?

Comment: I don't understand your reply to my comment.

Comment: actually there is a work which take 15 to 20 minutes, during this work database conectivity lose(means db server network down). how to handle this? i mean when database server again connect on network then at this time how to resume work again?
1 thing more database server and application server both on different machine and application server connect with database server through connection string.